# "Driver not capable" exception in Hive JDBC web application

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, hadoop, hive, cloudera

### " java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Simba][JDBC](10220) Driver not capable. "

- The above exception is giving when I'm executing my Java EE webapplication with Hive 0.13 in Eclipse (Kepler).
- **Due to below line:** 
                    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query, **ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE**);

**NOTE:**
        - The application is executing properly with query parameter of the above method.
        - But, This exception is coming just because of last 2 parameters of above method, nothing but ResultSet types.

**I Followed Configurations:**

- ***Cloudera Hive JDBC Driver class***: com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver
- ***Connection URL***: jdbc:hive2://192.168.1.135:10000/yottadb6
- ***Cloudera Software***: cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.3.0-0-vmware
- *Hive v0.13*
- *Cloudera Hive Jdbc drivers 2.5.3*
- *Apache Tomcat 7.0*
- *JDK 1.7*

**Q:  Can any body resolve the above problem as early as possible?**

Answer (score 3):

Those parameters (`ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`) are not supported by the Hive project's JDBC Driver. In fact, the Hive source code has a specific test to ensure that an exception IS thrown when those parameters are used:

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/itests/hive-unit/src/test/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/TestJdbcDriver2.java#L2046

Probably the same is true of the Cloudera driver you're using.